# Nodejs encrypt AES 256 / decrypt in java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

how I can decrypt something that I encrypted in nodejs?
Here is a snippet of my code in **node.js**:

```
function encrypt(cryptkey, iv, cleardata) {
    var encipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', cryptkey, iv),
        encryptdata  = encipher.update(cleardata, 'utf8', 'binary');

    encryptdata += encipher.final('binary');
    var encode_encryptdata = new Buffer(encryptdata, 'binary').toString('base64');
    return encode_encryptdata;
}
```

Here is my attempt to decrypt the node.js output with **Java**:

```
public static String decrypt(String src) {
    String decrypted = "";
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), makeIv());
        decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(src)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return decrypted;
}

static AlgorithmParameterSpec makeIv() {
    try {
        return new IvParameterSpec(ENCRYPTION_IV.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

static Key makeKey() {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] key = md.digest(ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please show us how you generated the key in NodeJS. As an IV should be indistinguishable from random, the following line is not correct as it assumes that the IV consists of characters instead: `ENCRYPTION_IV.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Comment: see this blog post http://srcode.org/2014/05/07/java-and-nodejs-on-aes/